# How to send ADMIN AJAX request?

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax, admin-controller

I need to retrieve some information from my custom admin controller  using AJAX.
But when AJAX is used I get current page's entire **HTML** !

I simply want to get some `JSON` data from my custom controller. That I will implement later on.

I'm calling my custom controller from a block in this

```
URL .../admin/admin/order_shipment/new/order_id/...
```

Here is my ajax call

```
 var param = 'form_key='+window.FORM_KEY;
         $.ajax({
                 showLoader: true,
                 url: "admin/PostaPlus/PostaPlusShipping/HSCodes",
                 data: param,
                 type: "POST",
                // dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {                        
                    alert(data);                        
                    console.log(data);
                 });
```

Here is my custom controller codes,

```
<?php
 namespace PostaPlus\PostaPlusShipping\Controller\Adminhtml;
 use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

 class HSCodes extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

   protected $resultJsonFactory;

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory 
        )
  {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    //return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['a' => 'b']);
    return 'test string';
  }

  public function indexAction(){

    //echo 'test string';
  }
}
```

Here is my route file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
     <router id="admin_hs_codes">
      <route id="PostaPlus" frontName="PostaPlus">
        <module name="PostaPlus_PostaPlusShipping"/>
      </route>
    </router>
 </config>
```

Comment: Any reason why you have `admin_hs_codes` instead of `admin` for your router id? Try changing it and clearing cache.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231316/100241
This helped me and save the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried all of the above methods but non of them are working or incomplete so I had decided to answer it in details:
Following will be module minimal diagram

[image]

1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="groupproduct" id="groupproduct">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Textmimedia_Partpicker"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Levosoft_Partpicker" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

3) Need to declare admin router

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="groupproduct" id="groupproduct">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Levosoft_Partpicker"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

4)

```
<?php


namespace Levosoft\Partpicker\Controller\Adminhtml\Imagetag;

/**
 * Class Save
 *
 * @package Levosoft\Partpicker\Controller\Adminhtml\Imagetag
 */
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            return $this->jsonResponse('your response');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create json response
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function jsonResponse($response = '')
    {
        return $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($response)
        );
    }
}
```

---

Now Client Part which is actually bit tricky I am calling it in js file like somefilename.js

```
var ajaxRequest;
                var saveUrl = gpImageTagSaveUrl+'?isAjax=true'; //module url declared globally in module;

                ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: saveUrl,
                    data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#loader').show();
                    }
                });
                //Show successfully for submit message
                ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#ajaxResponse").html(response);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                });

                //On failure of request this function will be called
                ajaxRequest.fail(function () {
                    //show error
                    $("#ajaxResponse").html('Oops, An error occured, please' +
                        ' try again later!');
                    $('#loader').hide();
                });
```

`gpImageTagSaveUrl` is globel variable which will hold your modules url you can declare it  in some js file like following

[image]

I had used catalog_product_edit.xml file because I want it at product edit location you can add it in your required file or in default.xml if required on all.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Levosoft_Partpicker::js.phtml"
                   name="custom_js_backend"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now in js.phtml declare action url like following:

```
<script>
    require([
        "prototype"
    ], function () {
        window.gpImageTagSaveUrl = '<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('groupproduct/imagetag/save')?>';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but the **admin Ajax requests** only pass in `GET` anyway for me.

I had the same problem as you and I solved my problem with passing the request in `GET` and it works properly.

Another very **important** thing is to disable the admin secret key in URL otherwise you can't access to your controller.

You can remove it in : `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > security > Add Secret Key to URLs > No`.

Also You should use `dataType: 'json'` to not return the **html code response**.

Admin AJAX exemple :

> adminhtml/templates/file.phtml

```
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        var ajaxRequest;
        ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminrouter/folder/index'); ?>",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {id : 1}, //exemple
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                jQuery('#loader').show();
            }
        });
            //Show successfully for submit message
        ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            jQuery("#ajaxResponse").html(response);
            jQuery('#loader').hide();
        });

            //On failure of request this function will be called
        ajaxRequest.fail(function () {
            //show error
            jQuery("#ajaxResponse").html('Oops, An error occured, please try again later!');
            jQuery('#loader').hide();
        });
    });
```

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Controller/Adminhtml/Folder/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Folder;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
        ,\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function execute() {

        //get AjaxQuery params, GET method !
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->logger->info($params); // For debug
        \Zend_Debug::dump($params);   // For debug

        //Send response to Ajax query
        $data = 200;
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $result->setData($data);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you or someone else.

Comment: this ajax "GET" call instead of "POST" helped me out i also dont know why but this helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery first.
Use this to code to do it:

```
require([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
     //your code to send ajax request here
    $.ajax({
        showLoader: true, 
        url: "admin/PostaPlus/PostaPlusShipping/HSCodes", 
        data: param,
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) { 
        alert(data); console.log(data); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I did  added like that and functions are working fine. Only AJAX return has the problem, 

<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){ 
 hscodes= { 
            
           ...............
           ...............
});
</script>

Comment: Try echoing the value in controller action and use .success() function instead of .done() in your ajax call

Comment: Tested as below but still same. 
changed in controller,
public function execute()
 {
  //return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['a' => 'b']);
  echo 'test string';

changed in JS, 
.success(function (data){
                     alert(data);                        
                       console.log(data);
                    })

But same results

Comment: Do you get any error ?? Try to use firebug in Firefox it will show you error

Comment: No errors. I get output as entire current page as html codes. I check in Chrome developer tool only.

Comment: I noticed that even if I dont give any URL  like this url: ""  I still get same page htmls.

Comment: Idk about chrome.  Are you sure your ajax request is reaching your action ??? Use firebug then you may see the html response. It may be a 404 page as your url may be wrong. Try to check if you have correct url. Try to acess the url in new tab entering in address bar  , see if you are getting the 404 page

Comment: I think its not reaching my custom controller action. This phtml file is from MG core Shipment controller. And I'm trying to access my custom controller . I think ajax request is not reaching to my controller. How do I fix this?
Basically I 'v rewrite core module controllers for my module

Comment: var url =' <?php echo $block->getUrl("module_name/controller/action/")';?>' use this.  Am on phone so can not format the answer properly

Comment: I get this Url when I console log . But if i check this url in a new tab I get re directed to admin home page.

http://localhost:8080/mg1/admin/PostaPlusShipping/HSCodes/index/key/0798f723b5565ebf9ab856ee7b87fe4061ffbee3dda086b6621d41af3408cec3/

Appreciated very much your help. 
Really appreciated mate ;)

Comment: PostaPlus is your module handle. PostaPlus/HSCodes/index pass this to get   $block->getUrl(). Like this $block->getUrl("PostaPlus/HSCodes/index");

Answer (score 0):

Add your controller file at

```
PostaPlus\PostaPlusShipping\Controller\Adminhtml\PostaPlusShipping\HSCodes.php
```

Now your ajax url is routname\controller\action

**PostaPlus\PostaPlusShipping\HSCodes**

add ajax code

```
var param = 'ajax=1';
     $.ajax({
       showLoader: true,
       url: YOUR_URL_HERE,
       data: param,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'json'
         }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
      });
```

Change controller execute method

```
public function execute()
  {
    return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['a' => 'b']);
  }
```

Comment: I created PostaPlusShipping folder and moved HSCodes class file in it. I tried with same ajax URL but still I get html codes. I think something to do with my routes.xml file?  Otherwise how could it returns html values even if I dont specify a URL? any suggestions on how to resolve this routes.xml?

Comment: update answer please check it

Comment: After doing all these changes I'm getting html response of admin home page.  My request is redirected to home page from server and getting it as html codes

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late but I found the solution

You can simple override admin resource const in your controller. Add to your controller const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Widget::widget_instance'; or extend Magento\CatalogWidget\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Widget.

No need to disable admin secret key. And Post method will work.

Solution found in Magento_PageBuilder module. Class Magento\PageBuilder\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\Element\ProductTotals.

plus you can pass url in xml
[image]

and your js file
[image]